# How can I get SAML to redirect to the right IdP?

Tags: identity, saml-2.0, federated-identity

We want to provide seamless access for all our users to SP's like publishers. The SP's are independent and provide services to a lot of different companies, i.e., we each have independent IdP solutions.

We want it to work as if there were no authentication, i.e., the user find a link on the Internet and follow it. If the site provide special services (that we pay for) for our users we would like them to use our own IdP (but only for our own users) to authenticate them.

Our current SAML setup requires that the SP support IP-address recognition and/or use specific domain names, i.e., the user access a specific domain name or come from our IP-ranges so the SP knows which IdP to redirect to but if our user comes from any other IP-address and don't access a specific URL the system is lost.

How is this solved?

I think a cookie given by the SP every time the user gets authenticated (from our network which the SP recognizes) can solve this but is that the standard? And it is not really a solution as it requires that our users have visited them at least once from our network!

Comment: Which SAML service do you use ? Doesn't it provide any option to restrict IP ranges ? Or did I get the question wrong ?

Comment: I am using SimpleSAMLPHP but it doesn't matter. :-)
It is a little complicated but the point is that my company and many other companies use the same SP's, e.g., publishers and for them to be able to figure out which IdP to talk to they use IP address recognition or specific domain names.
I will update my question with our goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't so much a SAML question as it is an identity provider discovery problem which isn't specific to the protocol. How is a publisher supposed to know / decide that a particular user should be redirected to your IdP via SAML or any other protocol? This isn't a tractable problem in a general sense. The publisher and you will need to agree on a contract between two entities (you and these publishers) when it comes to these special users / services.

One possible implementation of IdP discovery that doesn't involve domains or IP ranges is a dynamic lookup of the IdP based on the user's identity. User clicks a link, navigates to the publisher site and attempts to login with (for example) his identity of myname@mycompany.com . The publisher can then do a lookup of mycompany.com in their identity store of special users / services / IdPs and determine that this user should not be allowed to login with local (publisher-managed) credentials. Instead, the user should be sent to some 3rd party IdP via a SAML authentication request. The publisher can do this at the time of user login but before the user has a chance to enter their publisher-managed credentials, be it via your favorite AJAX technique or some other form of UI gratification.

The publisher could use a persistent cookie so that the next time this user comes to this publisher they'll know that this user "belongs" to a 3rd party IdP and redirect accordingly.